# Python Beautiful Soup Web Scraping Transfermkt Arrays Not all Same Length

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape data for teams over a period of years across countries from https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1/plus/?saison_id=2019

This site is an example of what I am looking to scrape including the table with squad size, etc. in the middle of the page as well as the table with the match data on the right side of the page. I am using Beautiful Soup in python.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

#create a dictionary for league and iterate over seasons
dct_GB1 = {}
dct_IT1 = {}
dct_ES1 = {}
dct_L1 = {}
dct_FR1 = {}
dct_PO1 = {}
dct_NL1 = {}
dct_TR1 = {}
dct_BE1 = {}
dct_UKR1 = {}
dct_A1 = {}
dct_GR1 = {}
dct_TS1 = {}
dct_SC1 = {}
dct_KR1 = {}
dct_C1 = {}
dct_PL1 = {}
dct_DK1 = {}
dct_ER1 = {}
dct_RO1 = {}
dct_SE1 = {}
dct_ZYP1 = {}
dct_NO1 = {}
dct_KAS1 = {}
dct_UNG1 = {}
dct_ISR1 = {}
dct_BU1 = {}
dct_WER1 = {}
dct_SLO1 = {}
dct_SL1 = {}
dct_AZ1 = {}
dct_BOS1 = {}
dct_MAL1 = {}
dct_ALB1 = {}
dct_MAZ1 = {}
dct_ARM1 = {}
dct_GE1N = {}
dct_FI1 = {}
dct_MO1N = {}
dct_LET1 = {}
dct_MNE1 = {}
dct_KO1 = {}
dct_LUX1 = {}
dct_LI1 = {}
dct_EST1 = {}
dct_IS1 = {}
dct_WAL1 = {}
dct_FARO = {}
dct_AND1 = {}
dct_IR1 = {}
dct_NIR1 = {}
dct_SMR1 = {}
dct_GI1 = {}
dct_GB2 = {}
dct_ES2 = {}
dct_IT2 = {}
dct_FR2 = {}
dct_L2 = {}
dct_NL2 = {}
dct_TR2 = {}
dct_PO2 = {}
dct_A2 = {}
dct_C2 = {}
dct_BE2 = {}
dct_GRS2 = {}
dct_RO2 = {}
dct_PL2 = {}
dct_UN2 = {}

for m in range(2007,2020):
    dct_GB1['df_GB1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_IT1['df_IT1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_ES1['df_ES1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_L1['df_L1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_FR1['df_FR1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_PO1['df_PO1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_NL1['df_NL1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_TR1['df_TR1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_BE1['df_BE1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_UKR1['df_UKR1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_A1['df_A1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_GR1['df_GR1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_TS1['df_TS1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_SC1['df_SC1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_KR1['df_KR1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_C1['df_C1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_PL1['df_PL1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_DK1['df_DK1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_ER1['df_ER1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_RO1['df_RO1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_SE1['df_SE1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_ZYP1['df_ZYP1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_NO1['df_NO1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_KAS1['df_KAS1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_UNG1['df_UNG1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_ISR1['df_ISR1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_BU1['df_BU1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_WER1['df_WER1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_SLO1['df_SLO1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_SL1['df_SL1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_AZ1['df_AZ1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_BOS1['df_BOS1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_MAL1['df_MAL1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_ALB1['df_ALB1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_MAZ1['df_MAZ1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_ARM1['df_ARM1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_GE1N['df_GE1N_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_FI1['df_FI1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_MO1N['df_MO1N_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_LET1['df_LET1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_MNE1['df_MNE1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_KO1['df_KO1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_LUX1['df_LUX1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_LI1['df_LI1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_EST1['df_EST1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_IS1['df_IS1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_WAL1['df_WAL1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_FARO['df_FARO_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_AND1['df_AND1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_IR1['df_IR1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_NIR1['df_NIR1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_SMR1['df_SMR1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_GI1['df_GI1_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_GB2['df_GB2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_ES2['df_ES2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_IT2['df_IT2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_FR2['df_FR2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_L2['df_L2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_NL2['df_NL2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_TR2['df_TR2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_PO2['df_PO2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_A2['df_A2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_C2['df_C2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_BE2['df_BE2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_GRS2['df_GRS2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_RO2['df_RO2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_PL2['df_PL2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()
    dct_UN2['df_UN2_%s' % m] = pd.DataFrame()

#list of URL bases for each league
league_urls = (['https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1/plus/?saison_id=', 
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/serie-a/startseite/wettbewerb/IT1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/laliga/startseite/wettbewerb/ES1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/ligue-1/startseite/wettbewerb/FR1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/liga-nos/startseite/wettbewerb/PO1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/eredivisie/startseite/wettbewerb/NL1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/super-lig/startseite/wettbewerb/TR1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/jupiler-pro-league/startseite/wettbewerb/BE1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/UKR1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/A1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/super-league-1/startseite/wettbewerb/GR1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/fortuna-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/TS1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/scottish-premiership/startseite/wettbewerb/SC1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/1-hnl/startseite/wettbewerb/KR1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/super-league/startseite/wettbewerb/C1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/pko-ekstraklasa/startseite/wettbewerb/PL1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/superligaen/startseite/wettbewerb/DK1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/super-liga-srbije/startseite/wettbewerb/SER1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/liga-1/startseite/wettbewerb/RO1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/allsvenskan/startseite/wettbewerb/SE1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/protathlima-cyta/startseite/wettbewerb/ZYP1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/eliteserien/startseite/wettbewerb/NO1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/KAS1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/nemzeti-bajnoksag/startseite/wettbewerb/UNG1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/ligat-haal/startseite/wettbewerb/ISR1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/efbet-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/BU1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/vysheyshaya-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/WER1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/fortuna-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/SLO1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/prva-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/SL1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/premyer-liqa/startseite/wettbewerb/AZ1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/premijer-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/BOS1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/MAL1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/kategoria-superiore/startseite/wettbewerb/ALB1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/prva-makedonska-fudbalska-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/MAZ1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/bardzragujn-khumb/startseite/wettbewerb/ARM1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/crystalbet-erovnuli-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/GE1N/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/veikkausliiga/startseite/wettbewerb/FI1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/divizia-nationala/startseite/wettbewerb/MO1N/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/virsliga/startseite/wettbewerb/LET1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/telekom-1-cfl/startseite/wettbewerb/MNE1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/superliga-e-kosoves/startseite/wettbewerb/KO1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/bgl-ligue/startseite/wettbewerb/LUX1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/a-lyga/startseite/wettbewerb/LI1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/premium-liiga/startseite/wettbewerb/EST1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/pepsi-max-deild/startseite/wettbewerb/IS1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/cymru-premier/startseite/wettbewerb/WAL1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/betri-deildin/startseite/wettbewerb/FARO/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/primera-divisio/startseite/wettbewerb/AND1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/IR1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/danske-bank-premiership/startseite/wettbewerb/NIR1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/campionato-sammarinese/startseite/wettbewerb/SMR1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/gibraltar-national-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GI1/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/championship/startseite/wettbewerb/GB2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/laliga2/startseite/wettbewerb/ES2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/serie-b/startseite/wettbewerb/IT2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/ligue-2/startseite/wettbewerb/FR2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/2-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/keuken-kampioen-divisie/startseite/wettbewerb/NL2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/1-lig/startseite/wettbewerb/TR2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/liga-portugal-2/startseite/wettbewerb/PO2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/2-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/A2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/challenge-league/startseite/wettbewerb/C2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/proximus-league/startseite/wettbewerb/BE2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/super-league-2/startseite/wettbewerb/GRS2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/liga-2/startseite/wettbewerb/RO2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/fortuna-1-liga/startseite/wettbewerb/PL2/plus/?saison_id=',
                'https://www.transfermarkt.com/nemzeti-bajnoksag-ii-/startseite/wettbewerb/UN2/plus/?saison_id='])
```

This is my setup with all the URL's to iterate over each season. Then I am trying to pull the data using the code below:

```
#Scraping part
#The first loop is for each url in our URL-list
for m in range(0, len(league_urls)):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    #The second loop is for each year we want to scrape
    for n in range(2007,2020):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        df_soccer1 = None
        url = league_urls[m] + str(n)
        headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        #Table 1 with information about the value
        table = soup.find("table", {"class" : "items"})

        team = []
        squad = []
        age = []
        foreigners = []
        total_market_value = []
        average_market_value = []

        for row in table.findAll('tr'):
            try:
                col = row.findAll('td')
                team.append(col[2].text)
                squad.append(col[3].text)
                age.append(col[4].text)
                foreigners.append(col[5].text)
                total_market_value.append(col[6].text)
                average_market_value.append(col[7].text)
            except:
                pass

        team = [elem.replace('\n','').replace('\xa0','').strip() for elem in team]

        #Table 2 with information about placement, goals and points
        df_soccer2 = None

        table2 = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "responsive-table"})

        team2 = []
        place = []
        matches = []
        difference = []
        pts = []

        if len(table2) <= 2:
            for row in table2[1].findAll('tr'):
                try:
                    col = row.findAll('td')
                    team2.append(col[2].text)
                    place.append(col[0].text)
                    matches.append(col[3].text)
                    difference.append(col[4].text)
                    pts.append(col[5].text)
                except:
                    pass
        else:
            #Sometimes the information you need is in another table
            for row in table2[2].findAll('tr'):
                try:
                    col = row.findAll('td')
                    team2.append(col[2].text)
                    place.append(col[0].text)
                    matches.append(col[3].text)
                    difference.append(col[4].text)
                    pts.append(col[5].text)
                except:
                    pass
                
        team2 = [elem.replace('\n','').replace('\xa0','').strip() for elem in team2]

        df_soccer1 = pd.DataFrame({'Team': team[1:], 'Season': n, 'Squad': squad[1:], 'Age': age[1:], 'Foreigners': foreigners[1:],
                                     'Total Value': total_market_value[1:], 'Average value': average_market_value[1:]})

        df_soccer2 = pd.DataFrame({'Team': team2, 'Place': place, 'Matches': matches, 'Difference': difference,
                                     'Points': pts})

        #Store all dictionaries in a list
        dct_all = [dct_GB1,dct_IT1,dct_ES1,dct_L1,dct_FR1,dct_PO1,dct_NL1,dct_TR1,dct_BE1,dct_UKR1,dct_A1,
                   dct_GR1,dct_TS1,dct_SC1,dct_KR1,dct_C1,dct_PL1,dct_DK1,dct_ER1,dct_RO1,dct_SE1,dct_ZYP1,dct_NO1,
                   dct_KAS1,dct_UNG1,dct_ISR1,dct_BU1,dct_WER1,dct_SLO1,dct_SL1,dct_AZ1,dct_BOS1,dct_MAL1,dct_ALB1,
                   dct_MAZ1,dct_ARM1,dct_GE1N,dct_FI1,dct_MO1N,dct_LET1,dct_MNE1,dct_KO1,dct_LUX1,dct_LI1,dct_EST1,
                   dct_IS1,dct_WAL1,dct_FARO,dct_AND1,dct_IR1,dct_NIR1,dct_SMR1,dct_GI1,dct_GB2,dct_ES2,dct_IT2,
                   dct_FR2,dct_L2,dct_NL2,dct_TR2,dct_PO2,dct_A2,dct_C2,dct_BE2,dct_GRS2,dct_RO2,dct_PL2,dct_UN2]
        
        #Merge df_soccer1 and df_soccer2 for each season
        dct_all[l]['df_bl_%s' % n] = pd.merge(df_soccer1, df_soccer2, how="inner", left_on="Team", right_on="Team")
```

The problem is I get an error:

ValueError: arrays must all be same length

I have figure out I get this since for some of the teams/countries not every year is available. Is there a solution to this problem where I can scrape all the data and it can just put blanks in for the missing years?'

EDIT:

Here is the error I get

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-534e3145bb5f> in <module>
     50 
     51 
---> 52         df_soccer1 = pd.DataFrame({'Team': team[1:], 'Season': n, 'Squad': squad[1:], 'Age': age[1:], 'Foreigners': foreigners[1:],
     53                                      'Total Value': total_market_value[1:], 'Average value': average_market_value[1:]})
     54 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    527 
    528         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 529             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    530         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    531             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    285             arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    286         ]
--> 287     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    288 
    289 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype, verify_integrity)
     78         # figure out the index, if necessary
     79         if index is None:
---> 80             index = extract_index(arrays)
     81         else:
     82             index = ensure_index(index)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in extract_index(data)
    399             lengths = list(set(raw_lengths))
    400             if len(lengths) > 1:
--> 401                 raise ValueError("arrays must all be same length")
    402 
    403             if have_dicts:

ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be helpful if you'd specify what part of your code throws the error. I'm assuming its the part where you initialize `df_soccer1`.

Your problem is that `try:`  executes until it doesn't, which means if there are only 5 `<td>` in a `<tr>`, text is appended to `team`, `squad` and `age`, then an error is thrown because you are iterating over more `<td>` than there are and nothing is appended to `foreigners` and the other two data points. This means your arrays are of uneven length.

Following code seperates the steps, it first extracs the text from all `<td>` and only if all of them were returned, the information is appended, else '' is appended.

```
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
            try:
                col = row.findAll('td')
                team_ = col[2].text
                squad_ = col[3].text
                age_ = col[4].text
                foreigners_ = col[5].text
                total_ = col[6].text
                average_ = col[7].text
                team.append(team_)
                squad.append(squad_)
                age.append(age_)
                foreigners.append(foreigners_)
                total_market_value.append(total_)
                average_market_value.append(average_)
            except:
                team.append('')
                squad.append('')
                age.append('')
                foreigners.append('')
                total_market_value.append('')
                average_market_value.append('')
```

You could also use try/except (or more efficiently if/else) for each of the six data points individually, you need to be carful however if the rows that don't work properly really contain the information you're interested in.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the error message